# dataLayer.push() doesn't trigger an HTTP request

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I am triggering a Google Analytics event on page load with this code:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'GAevent',
    'eventCategory': 'data-harvest',
    'eventAction': 'form-submitted',
    'eventLabel': 'vr-gear'
});
```

It happens on `document.ready()` and there are no errors in console, but for some reason it doesn't trigger any HTTP request. Any idea why is that?

Comment: Check GTM documentation. `dataLayer.push({event:'GAevent',action:'someaction',label:'somedata'});`. `GAevent` must be first registered in GTM. `action` and `label` values are arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using Google Tag Manager, then that's the expected result. The DataLayer is a specific JSON object that GTM defines and deploys in order to fire tags and also acquire various pieces of information from the page. It uses the special 'event' to fire custom tags. Google Analytics by itself does not utilise the dataLayer so that's why, without GTM, you won't see any HTTP requests.

If you are using GTM then you need have edit access to it at least, and you'll also need to:

1. create a custom event trigger that uses that specific event value (`GAevent`)

[image]

2. create variables that use those other event-based parameters (`eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel`)

[image]

3. and a tag that uses all those pieces together.

[image]

Beyond all this, you'll need to [familiarise yourself with GTM](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide). It would be kind of pointless if your site uses GTM, but you (assuming you're the dev or analyst) are not provided access.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using the GTM. Would you mind explaining a little more about it, how to set it up? I am asking that because I have no access to the GTM that we are using.